# 3D Cursor acting up

Tags: 3d-cursor

When I do any transformations to an object in blender it seems to be locked to the 3D cursor. How do I fix this?

Here is a link to a screen recording which shows the problem https://youtu.be/9qcKDQSSMg0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've chosen the 3D cursor as transform pivot point, switch to *Median Point* for example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will mark your answer as the correct one after the time limit has passed